# Remove everything between specific characters

Tags: r

I have a string that looks like this:

```
BA46_05-07-2019_rxn2_AAGAACATCCCTCTCC
```

I want to remove everything between `rxn2` and `BA46_`

Desired end results:

`BA46_rxn2_AAGAACATCCCTCTCC`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub("BA46_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*rxn2","BA46_rx2","BA46_05-07-2019_rxn2_AAGAACATCCCTCTCC")
```

Comment: I'm pretty bad with regex, so I'm trying to learn more about it, and I was curious what would be the benefit of using ```"BA46_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*rxn2"``` over just ```"BA46.*rxn2"```? I think they both work, though I'm definitely still just learning!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x <- "BA46_05-07-2019_rxn2_AAGAACATCCCTCTCC"

sub("_[0-9\\-]*_" , "_" , x)
```

- output

```
[1] "BA46_rxn2_AAGAACATCCCTCTCC"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

str_remove(string, '\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{4}\\_')

[1] "BA46_rxn2_AAGAACATCCCTCTCC"
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
sub('(.*BA46_).*(rxn2.*)','\\1\\2', 'BA46_05-07-2019_rxn2_AAGAACATCCCTCTCC')
```

I would go with this because it

1. does not depend on what is being deleted (which is crucial IMHO)
2. only contains `BA46_` and `rxn2` once, thus reducing the room for error